# "Invalid padding" exception in ColdFusion encrypt/decrypt

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

my code throws an exception I can't understand. I'm still new in programming so bear with me. This is my code:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="false">
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
<body>

    <cfset key = generateSecretKey("AES")>

    <cfscript>
        if (isDefined("form")) {
            encFieldnamesArr = listToArray(form.fieldnames);
            decFieldnamesArr = arrayNew(1);

            for (paramName in encFieldnamesArr) {
                arrayAppend(decFieldnamesArr, "#decrypt(paramName, key, 'AES', 'HEX')#");
            }
        }
    </cfscript>

    <cfform>
        <cfinput name="#encrypt("firstName", key, "AES", "HEX")#" type="text" />
        <cfinput name="#encrypt("lastName", key, "AES", "HEX")#" type="text" />
        <cfinput type="submit" name="#encrypt("action", key, "AES", "HEX")#" value="submit" />
    </cfform>

</body>
</html>
```

It throws this exception:

```
 An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: Invalid padding..

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/test/index.cfm: line 17

15 : 
16 :            for (paramName in encFieldnamesArr) {
17 :                arrayAppend(decFieldnamesArr, "#decrypt(paramName, key, 'AES', 'HEX')#");
18 :            }
19 :        }
```

What does "invalid padding" mean? Thanks

Comment: Can you please post a [small *self-contained* repro case](http://www.sscce.org/) that we can copy+paste+run? Obviously, do not include your real `key` Use a dummy value or generate a throw away key for demo purposes. My guess would be you are using a different key to decrypt than the one you used to encrypt.

Comment: Hello, I just added all my code. it's okay, I'm not using it for an app, I was just curious if I could do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decrypting, you have to use the exact same `key` used to encrypt the value. Your code is generating a totally new key every time the page loads:

```
<cfset key = generateSecretKey("AES")>
```

So the code is using one key to encrypt. Then when the form is submitted, it uses a completely different key to `decrypt()`. Hence the error.

**Example:**

```
<cfscript>
  // WORKS: encrypt and decrypt with the same key
  key = generateSecretKey("AES");
  text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
  encrypted = encrypt(text, key, 'AES', 'HEX');
  decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key, 'AES', 'HEX');
  writeOutput("<br>text="& text);
  writeOutput("<br>key="& key);
  writeOutput("<br>encrypted="& encrypted);
  writeOutput("<br>decrypted="& decrypted);

  // FAILS: Decrypting with a *different* key will fail
  key = generateSecretKey("AES");
  writeOutput("<br>key="& key);
  decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, key, 'AES', 'HEX');
</cfscript>
```

I realize the above is just an experiment, but a few tips:

1. `FORM` is a system structure, so it should always be defined. Typically you would check for the existence of a specific form field name instead. ie

   `structKeyExists(FORM, "someFieldName")`
2. Since you are not using any of the extra features of cfform/cfinput (which are not great anyway), just use plain a html `<form>` and `<input>` tags.  Using the CF versions will cause CF to add a lot of unnecessary javascript code to your page.
3. No need for double quotes or `#` signs around the decrypt. Just use:

   `decrypt(paramName, key, 'AES', 'HEX')`

Comment: I totally forgot that the page loads again when passing the form, since I was planning to use this on an ajax request, I had a different thing in mind. Thanks! :D